# Irreducibility of polynomials that almost satisfy the Eisenstein's Criterion for UFDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I recently saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757016/on-the-irreducibility-of-a-polynomial-that-almost-satisfies-eisensteins-criteri) question about polynomials that almost satify the Eisenstein's criterion.

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_nx^n\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Suppose there is a prime $p$ such that $p$ does not divide $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$, $p$ divides the other coefficients and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$, then $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ if and only if $f$ has no rational root.

From the answer, it was shown that if $f$ can be reduced, say $f=gh$, then either $g$ or $h$ is linear.

Now, here are my questions.

1. Am I correct that the approach in the answer is applicable to UFDs? Of course, we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by the field of fractions. I can't see any special property of $\mathbb{Z}$ used that is not satisfied by any UFD.
2. Is my interpretation of the proof correct that at the "worst" case, $f$ can only be reduced to a product of a linear polynomial and a polynomial of degree $n-1$? Specifically, if $f=gh$, then $g$ and $h$ are already the irreducible factors of $f$?

Comment: Yeah, I believe it works. The only difference is we're considering $\bmod \mathfrak p$ where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal, instead of $p$ a prime number. Your interpretation in (2) is also correct. The criterion can also be further generalized to $f$ has an irreducible factor with degree more than $k$ when $p \mid a_0, a_1 \ldots a_k, p \nmid a_{k+1}$ and $p^2 \nmid a_0$.